# Why await can't be used from a normal function or the global scope

Tags: javascript

I was reading a blog that have the below sample code,

```
async function fAsync() {
    // actual return value is Promise.resolve(5)
    return 5;
}

// can't call "await fAsync()". Need to use then/catch
fAsync().then(r => console.log(`result is ${r}`));
```

In the blog this was mentioned that,

> > if we call an async function from a normal function or the global scope, we won’t be able to use await and will resort to vanilla promises:

My confusion is that why we can't use await there? The blog post is https://nikgrozev.com/2017/10/01/async-await/

Comment: In order to have a valid async await syntax and functionality, the await keyword needs to be called within an async function as well. If you had the whole code block in an async function, you could await the result of fAsync(). https://jsfiddle.net/gmsx42ny/

Comment: await only works in functions marked as async , this is why you cant use it outside an async function block an need to use then/catch

Comment: Just read first line of [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 6):

A "top level await" is currently at stage 2 (draft) on TC39's ECMAScript standard

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await

It has been at stage 2 for 3 years, so, I don't know if it will ever make it to stage 3 (candidate) let alone stage 4 (finished)

---

## EDIT

Original answer was in November 2018. In June 2019 **top level await graduated to stage 3 (candidate)**. Stage 4 is very likely to follow, but hard to say when.

Side note : If you want to dive deeper, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221) and some of its comments are informative on the subject.

Comment: Top level await is now available in most browsers